# Trouble “extracting by mask” with a raster (land cover) layer and a shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, clip

I cannot seem to get clip to run.  I am a bit of a novice and do not know where to start to try to resolve the issue.  I am attempting to clip a raster (of land cover values) by a set of polygons.  I have pasted below the error messages from the two most recent attempts of Extract by Mask and Raster Clip, and an image of a small portion of the map
Any ideas of where I should start?

[image: error messages]

[image: screen shot of map]

Comment: The error messages state "table name is invalid", yet you don't show the full parameter list that includes the output name. Please "Copy as Python snippet" from the geoprocessing Results history, so a legible copy of your command is available.

Comment: It also says: No spatial reference exists. Therefore it wouldn't know where the polygon was in relation to the raster anyway. Make sure both layers have an SRS, and preferably the same SRS.

Comment: ESRI tool that involve interactions between vector data and raster data will throw 999999 errors when those data are not referencing the same coordinate reference system.  Reproject one of your datasets to the CRS of the other and try again.

Comment: Thanks All.  I got it working.  As GBG suggested I needed to reproject the polygon data. I also had been naming the output file starting with a number (a non no).

Here is the finished, successful run:
# Replace a layer/table view name with a path to a dataset (which can be a layer file) or create the layer/table view within the script
# The following inputs are layers or table views: "NLCD_2016_Land_Cover_L48_20190424.img", "c6st_allLSPVP_ACEA"
arcpy.gp.ExtractByMask_sa("NLCD_2016_Land_Cover_L48_20190424.img", "c6st_allLSPVP_ACEA", "C:/db/lspvp/data/lspvp.gdb/LC2016_LSPVP_clip")

Comment: and the errored one:
# The following inputs are layers or table views: "NLCD_2016_Land_Cover_L48_20190424.img", "6st_allLSPVP_AEA_dates"
arcpy.Clip_management(in_raster="NLCD_2016_Land_Cover_L48_20190424.img", rectangle="-2294628.84479071 1252483.25642364 2121071.97139638 2540836.85146154", out_raster="C:/db/lspvp/data/lspvp.gdb/lc2016_lspvp_clip.img", in_template_dataset="6st_allLSPVP_AEA_dates", nodata_value="#", clipping_geometry="ClippingGeometry", maintain_clipping_extent="MAINTAIN_EXTENT")